# How do I give an error message if condition is not met?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im doing an assignment for a basic programming course.

I have a dataframe (csv-file) containing the columns:

```
   StudentID                       Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3 
0    s123456           Michael Andersen            7            7             4
1    s123789           Bettina Petersen           12           10            10
2    s123468             Thomas Nielsen           -3            7             2
3    s123579               Marie Hansen           10           12            12
4    s123579               Marie Hansen           10           12            12
5    s127848            Andreas Nielsen            2            2             2
6    s120799           Mads Westergaard           12           12            10
7    s123456           Michael Andersen            7            7             4
8    S184507  Andreas Døssing Mortensen            2            2             4
9    S129834             Jonas Jonassen            0           -3             4
10   S123481             Milad Mohammed           12           10             7
11   S128310                Abdul Jihad           10            4             7
12   S125493             Søren Sørensen            0            7             7
13   S128363                        123            4            7            10
14   S127463              Jensen Jensen            5            2            10
15   S120987                 Jeff Bezos           12           12            12
```

I need to make my program give an error message if a condition is not meet. In this instance if a student is in the dataframe more than once and if the grade given for an assignment is not on the scale of grades (-3, 0, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12):

The assignment is as follows:

If the user chooses to check for data errors, you must display a report of errors (if any) in the loaded data file. Your program must at least detect and display information about the following possible errors:
1. If two students in the data have the same student id.
2. If a grade in the data set is not one of the possible grades on the 7-step-scale.

How can I get around this?

I have tried to solve it like this, but no luck:

doubles = dataDuplicate["Name"].duplicated()

print(doubles)

grades = np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])

dataSortGrades = dataSortGrades.iloc[:,2:] #this gives

gradesNotInList = np.isin(dataSortGrades,grades)

if dataDuplicate["Name"] in doubles == True:
    print("Error")
else:
    print(#list of false values")

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far? Where are you running into issues?

Comment: ```
import pandas as pd 

# making data frame from csv file 
dataSort = pd.read_csv("Karakterer.csv") 
dataDuplicate = pd.read_csv("Karakterer.csv") 
dataSortGrades = pd.read_csv("Karakterer.csv")



# filter data that has duplictates
doubles = dataDuplicate["Name"].duplicated()

print(doubles)

grades = np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])

dataSortGrades = dataSortGrades.iloc[:,2:] #this gives

gradesNotInList = np.isin(dataSortGrades,grades)


if dataDuplicate["Name"] in doubles == True:
    print("Error")
else:
    print(something) #list of false values
```

Comment: Please edit this into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is:

```py
if condition:
    print(message)
```

where `condition` (or `not condition`) and `message` should be adjusted to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create 3 data frames. You can just create the dataframe and then perform you selections based on your conditions.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

data = """0    s123456           Michael Andersen            7            7             4
1    s123789           Bettina Petersen           12           10            10
2    s123468             Thomas Nielsen           -3            7             2
3    s123579               Marie Hansen           10           12            12
4    s123579               Marie Hansen           10           12            12
5    s127848            Andreas Nielsen            2            2             2
6    s120799           Mads Westergaard           12           12            10
7    s123456           Michael Andersen            7            7             4
8    S184507  Andreas Døssing Mortensen            2            2             4
9    S129834             Jonas Jonassen            0           -3             4
10   S123481             Milad Mohammed           12           10             7
11   S128310                Abdul Jihad           10            4             7
12   S125493             Søren Sørensen            0            7             7
13   S128363                        123            4            7            10
14   S127463              Jensen Jensen            5            2            10
15   S120987                 Jeff Bezos           12           12            12"""

#Make the data frame
data = [re.split(r"\s{2,}", line)[1:] for line in data.splitlines()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['StudentID', 'Name', 'Assignment1', 'Assignment2', 'Assignment3'])

#print the duplicates
print(f'###Duplicate studentIDs###')
print(df[df['StudentID'].duplicated()])

#print invalid grades
valid_grades = ('-3', '0', '2', '4', '7', '10', '12')
print(f'###Invalid grades###')
print(df[
    (df['Assignment1'].isin(valid_grades) == False) |
    (df['Assignment2'].isin(valid_grades) == False) |
    (df['Assignment3'].isin(valid_grades) == False)
])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
###Duplicate studentIDs###
  StudentID              Name Assignment1 Assignment2 Assignment3
4   s123579      Marie Hansen          10          12          12
7   s123456  Michael Andersen           7           7           4
###Invalid grades###
   StudentID           Name Assignment1 Assignment2 Assignment3
14   S127463  Jensen Jensen           5           2          10
```

Comment: Thank you!

I need this to work with an infinite amount of assignments and with an imported dsv file instead og typing in all the data. 

I think that data has to be: 
data=pd.read_csv("Karakterer.csv")

Comment: Yes this is just an example to show you since i dont have all your data. But this should be more than enough to allow you to complete your assignment. Remember we are not here to complete your homework for you. we are just trying to help you understand your problem and learn so you can apply it to your assignment.